# React js related problem. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, localhost

Hello community and thank you for your attention. I've been experiencing some troubles related to my localhost.
I have been unable to view the code from App.js file.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:3001', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setResponse(data.message));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <textarea
         value={message}
         onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)} 
         ></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>{response}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

What might have been the problem?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfpqP.png)

Additionally, the code from index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;
    
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'Hello World!'
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Do you have any suggestions?

── @testing-library/jest-dom@5.16.5
├── @testing-library/react@13.4.0
├── @testing-library/user-event@13.5.0
├── cors@2.8.5
├── express@4.18.2
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├── react-scripts@5.0.1
├── react@18.2.0
└── web-vitals@2.1.4
That's the list of the packages, which seemed to me OK to go with.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between your express API and your front-end server. Please run `npm run dev` and visit http://localhost:3000 to see your app

Comment: you should go to localhost:3000(where your react runs) and not localhost:3001